# Subgroups of symmetry Group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry

I'm reading *Matrix Groups for Undergraduates* by K.Tapp. In chapter $3$ he defines  symmetry group as the group of all isometries of $\mathbb{R^n}$ that carry $X\subset\mathbb{R^n}$onto itself:

$Symm(X)=\{f\in Isom(\mathbb{R^n}) : f(X)=X\}$

Then, he gives this characterization:

$Symm(X)=Symm^{+} \cup Symm^{-}$ , where the sets

$Symm^{\pm}(X)=\{\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ V & 1 \end{pmatrix}\in Symm(X) : det(A)=\pm1\}$ are called the proper and improper symmetry groups of $X$.

$A\in O(n)$ and $V\in\mathbb{R^n}$, $O(n)$ is the orthogonal group.

Then, he says:

**For any $X\subset\mathbb{R^n}$, $Symm^{+}\subset Symm(X)$ is a subgroups with index $1$ or $2$.**

I tried using *Lagrange's theorem* but i don't understand why index is $1$ or $2$. Can you help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $Symm^{+}$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $f:Symm(X)\to\{1,-1\}$ which sends $\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ V & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ to $\det(A)$.  In particular, the quotient $Symm(X)/Symm^+(X)$ is isomorphic to the image of $f$, which is a subgroup of $\{1,-1\}$.  That subgroup has either $1$ or $2$ elements, so $Symm^+(X)$ has index either $1$ or $2$.

Comment: Thank you very much Eric!